# AlarmManager - Notificação em tempo específico

Tags: android, android-alarmmanager

Estou tentando fazer disparar uma mensagem na tela através do `AlamManager` e `BroadCastReceiver`.

O tempo específico está sendo pego por um `TimePicker` exatamente como deve.

Mas a notificação acaba não sendo disparada na tela.

O código está dessa maneira:

```
@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) 
{
    Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();
    calSet.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    setAlarm(calSet);
}

private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCall)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm is set at" + targetCall.getTime(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCall.getTimeInMillis(), pendingintent);
    }
```

E a classe do `BroadcastReceiver` está dessa maneira:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Toast.makeText(arg0, "Your Time is up!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sua classe `AlarmReceiver` está declarada no `AndroidManifest.xml`? `<receiver android:name="pacote.onde.está.a.classe.AlarmReceiver" />`

Comment: não estava com receiver, não prestei atenção nisso, obrigado :D

Comment: Agora está tudo como deveria :D

Comment: Ok, vou colocar como resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inclua o `<receiver>` no `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<receiver android:name="pacote.onde.está.a.classe.AlarmReceiver" />
```